# Problems with installing C++ version > 4.7

Tags: 12.04, c++

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04.5

I want to install the latest version of C++. I used the following commands to install.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
```

However, when I then try to check for the version of C++ using

```
gcc --version
```

the output still shows version 4.6 instead of 4.9. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried installing v5.1 also, but it still says 4.6 when I use
     gcc --version

Comment: Installing `g++-4.9` doesn't overwrite the symbolic link to the system default version i.e. `/usr/bin/g++ --> /usr/bin/g++-4.6`. Although you *can* manually overwrite it *or* use the `update-alternatives` mechanism, many build systems respect a `CXX` variable so first try simply specifying `CXX="/usr/bin/g++-4.9"` on the build command line.

Answer (score -1):

compiler installs are special ... since your OS needs updates to get compiled by same version of compiler the kernel was compiled on, do not attempt nor expect a fresh compiler to become the default

... look in dir /etc/alternatives